# Select NULL Values in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

Here's my (PostgreSQL) table --

```
test=> create table people (name varchar primary key,
                            marriage_status varchar) ; 

test=> insert into people values ('Ken', 'married');
test=> insert into people values ('May', 'single');
test=> insert into people values ('Joe', NULL);
```

I want to select all people that are **not** known to be married, i.e., including those with NULL marriage_status.

This does **not** work --

```
test=> select * from people where marriage_status != 'married' ; 
 name | marriage_status 
------+-----------------
 May  | single
(1 row)
```

Of course this does --

```
test=> select * from people where marriage_status != 'married'
       or marriage_status is NULL ; 
 name | marriage_status 
------+-----------------
 May  | single
 Joe  |
```

The problem is that I'm accessing it from SQLAlchemy with --

```
...filter(or_(people.marriage_status!='married',
              people.marriage_status is None))
```

which gets translated to --

```
SELECT people.name as name,
       people.marriage_status as marriage_status
FROM people 
WHERE people.marriage_status != %(status_1)s OR False
sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.... {'status_1': 'married'}
```

And does **not** work --

```
test=> select * from people where marriage_status != 'married'
       or False; 
 name | marriage_status 
------+-----------------
 May  | single
(1 row)
```

neither does --

```
test=> select * from people where marriage_status != 'married'
       or NULL; 
 name | marriage_status 
------+-----------------
 May  | single
(1 row)
```

How should I select NULL values through SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

For **SQLAlchemy 0.7.9 and newer**
Please use the [answer from @jsnow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44679356/99594). !!!

For **SQLAlchemy 0.7.8 and older**

(as indicated by [@augurar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572431/augurar)): Because *sqlalchemy* uses *magic methods (operator overloading)* to create `SQL` constructs, it can only handle operator such as `!=` or `==`, but is not able to work with `is` (which is a very valid Python construct).

Therefore, to make it work with sqlalchemy, you should use:

```
...filter(or_(people.marriage_status!='married', people.marriage_status == None))
```

, basically replace the `is None` with `== None`. In this case your query will be translated properly to the following SQL:

```
SELECT people.name AS people_name, people.marriage_status AS people_marriage_status 
FROM people 
WHERE people.marriage_status IS NULL OR people.marriage_status != ?
```

See `IS NULL` in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).

Comment: pylint does not like comparing None with ==

Comment: If you want to get around pylint not liking comparing None with ==, you can use Table.column_name.is_(None). Also Table.column_name.isnot(None) replaces Table.column_name != None.

Comment: I think in this particular instance, `# noinspection PyComparisonWithNone,PyPep8` is just fine

Comment: is_(None) is a better way.

Comment: As @MortezaZakeri mentioned I also recommend like:
    ...filter(or_(people.marriage_status!='married', people.marriage_status .is_(None))) in flask-sqlalchemy==2.4.1

Answer (score 121):

Since SQLAlchemy 0.7.9 you may use the [is_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.is_) (or [is_not](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnOperators.is_not)) method of the column.

A filter expression like:

`filter(or_(people.marriage_status!='married', people.marriage_status.is_(None)))`

will generate the parameterized SQL:

`WHERE people.marriage_status != %(status_1)s OR people.marriage_status IS NULL`

Answer (score 29):

An elegant way to write it would be to use is_ and is_not, as shown in the following example:

```
query.filter(people.student.is_not(None)) 
query.filter(people.student.is_(None))
```

Answer (score 12):

The question is quite old, but for completeness, here the version I prefer for readability:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

query.filter(people.marriage_status == sa.null()) 
query.filter(people.marriage_status != sa.null())
```

Answer (score 1):

i ran into a similar problem

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/EVpxsNp5Ifg%5B1-25%5D

short answer:
 - there is not a column operator for IS (NOT) NULL now, but there will be

in the meantime you can use either:

filter(tablename.is_deleted.op("IS NOT")(True))

filter(coalesce(tablename.is_deleted, False) != True)

Comment: And now there are `.is_` and `.isnot` since 0.7.9, so this should be considered obsolete.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - cheers needed to use .isnot(None) instead of is not None..