# SQLAlchemy Core select where condition contains boolean expression `is False`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to use SQLAlchemy expression language to select columns with where condition to check boolean expression. example:

```
select([table]).\
    where(and_(table.c.col1 == 'abc',
               table.c.is_num is False 
    ))
```

This doesn't give syntax error, but evaluates the condition wrong. I cannot use == False which gives error. **SQLAlchemy Core** v.1.0.8

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602918/select-null-values-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: Also somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681231/sqlalchemy-boolean-value-of-this-clause-is-not-defined

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause

Comment: It is imperative that you copy whatever error message you received into the question, and *verbatim*. Now we just need to guess whichever of the many possible errors you might have encountered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [identity comparison operator `is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) cannot be overloaded in Python, so

```
table.c.is_num is False
```

compares the identities of the `Column` object and `False`, and since they're clearly not the same object, evaluates to False. By

> I cannot use == False which gives error

you probably mean that some Python linter adhering to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gives you a warning. Checking equality against True or False is still valid Python, though [unpythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id51) in the general sense – but it [does make sense in SQLAlchemy filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998010/flake8-complains-on-boolean-comparison-in-filter-clause) and it is [used in the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.and_). For example:

```
In [5]: t.c.bar == False
Out[5]: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7fdc355a1da0>

In [6]: print(_)
foo.bar = false
```

But: instead of comparing a boolean to a boolean you could use the value itself:

```
select([table]).\
    where(and_(table.c.col1 == 'abc',
               ~table.c.is_num
    ))
```

which would translate to (approximately):

```
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE col1 = 'abc' AND NOT is_num
```

since SQLAlchemy [`ColumnOperators`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators) overload the [`__invert__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.__invert__) to [`not_()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.not_). Some backends may not support a boolean type, but SQLAlchemy handles the conversion:

```
In [6]: print((~t.c.bar).compile(dialect=sqlite.dialect()))
foo.bar = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=true#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true), the way you should handle this is by using the true() or false() constants that you can import from SqlAlchemy. It would look like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import false

select([table]).\
    where(and_(table.c.col1 == 'abc',
               table.c.is_num == false() 
    ))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am specifically talking of sqlalchemy Core 1.0.8, what you have answered is for orm

Comment: Ah, sorry i missed that. It looks like instead of comparing to the boolean False, try comparing it to the True constant created by SqlAlchemy which you can read about here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=true#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true (I edited my answer to reflect this answer)

Comment: can you set the expression in the above code and show how exactly it is incorporated?

Comment: For sure. I used the false() method in the answer above (edited) check it out and try it to see if it works