# SQLAlchemy - Error on nested CASE

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want to transfer SQL to SQLAlchemy and have the case that I have nested case statements.

The simple case is working:

```
stmt = sqlalchemy.select([self.tusg_view_specials]).where(
    sqlalchemy.case([
        (self.tusg_view_specials.c.webo_close_date >= (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)), 1),
        (self.tusg_view_specials.c.wo_closed_date >= (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=61)), 1)
        ], else_=0),
    )
```

But when I have a nested case, means that the THEN is a case clause instead of a simple value:

```
stmt = sqlalchemy.select([self.tusg_view_specials]).where(
    sqlalchemy.case([
        (self.tusg_view_specials.c.webo_close_date >= (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)), 1),
        (self.tusg_view_specials.c.wo_closed_date >= (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=61)), 1),
        (self.tusg_view_specials.c.work_order_number is None,
            sqlalchemy.case([(self.tusg_view_specials.c.flag_is_abw == 1, 1)], else_=0))
        ], else_=0), <<-- This line is shown to cause the error
    )
```

I get the following error message, I don't know how to deal with it:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Ambiguous literal: False.  Use the 'text()' function to indicate a SQL expression literal, or 'literal()' to indicate a bound value.
```

I can read the text, but don't know how to interpret it. Search results on "nested case" on SQLAlchemy are very little to none.

Comment: The problem is not the nested case, but `self.tusg_view_specials.c.work_order_number is None`. The identity operator cannot be overloaded, and so that expression evaluates to False in Python. Did you mean `self.tusg_view_specials.c.work_order_number.is_(None)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select NULL Values in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602918/select-null-values-in-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As also Ilja Everilä wrote, the cause is the "IS None", which needs to be replaced by

```
table_instance.c.work_order_number.is_(None)
```

or

```
table_instance.c.work_order_number == None
```